# writing Christmas tree to a file.txt

Tags: c, for-loop, file-handling

I am trying to write the Christmas tree into a file "output.txt" using c by a symbol,"&", given in a file input.txt.

the problem is that the space and the new line do not work in my code and I get the output like this:
[image]
can anyone please help me to get this done?

this is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    
int main(void) {
  FILE* file1_read;
  FILE* file2_write;
    
  file1_read = fopen("input.txt", "r");
  file2_write = fopen("putput.txt", "w");
  char symbole = fgetc(file1_read);
    
  int height = 4;
      
  for (int i = 1; i <= height; i++) {   
    int starCount = (i * 2) - 1;
    int spaceCount = height - i + 1;
      
    // print out the spaces
    for (int j = 0; j < spaceCount; j++)
    fputc("  ", file2_write);
    
    // print out the stars
    for (int j = 0; j < starCount; j++)
    fputc(symbole, file2_write);
    
    // print new line
    fputc("\n", file2_write);
  }
  fclose(file2_write);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked that the files are actually opened successfully? ***Always*** check for failure from functions that can fail.

Comment: The first argument `fputc` should be a single character, not a string literal. Replace the double quotes with single quotes. See [the documentation of `fputc`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputc).

Comment: Treat the compiler warnings as errors

Comment: i get this warning.   note: passing argument to parameter here
int      fputc(int, FILE *);
                  ^
2 warnings generated.

Comment: thank you so much. it worked after using single quotes. :)

Comment: *'First argument [of] `fputc` [...]'* – or in *first* case use [`fputs`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fputs) instead, as you have two spaces in your string. In second case (the newline), `fputc` + character literal is more efficient as you do not need to iterate over a string that just contains one single character anyway.

Comment: By the way: *Why* do you get that bad output? `fputc` accepts an `int` as character (that still only should contain values in the valid range of the underlying character set!) – if you pass a string literal to as parameter it first decays to a pointer (type `char*`) which then is implicitly converted to an `int` – which might then contain an *arbitrary* value…